# xgboost.core.XGBoostError: need to call fit beforehand - when trying to predict through a pickled model

Tags: python, xgboost

I have created an XGBoost classifier and dumped the python file using joblib in a dat fileformat.

I am able to load it using joblib but when I try to use the loaded model to predict on new data, I see the error

```
 xgboost.core.XGBoostError: need to call fit beforehand
```

The original model that i trained was:

```
 XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
   colsample_bytree=0.6, eval_metric='error', gamma=0,
   learning_rate=0.125, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=8,
   min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=600, n_jobs=1,
   nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0,
   reg_alpha=0.2, reg_lambda=0.8, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
   silent=True, subsample=0.8)
```

The pickled model is:

```
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
   colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0,
   max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100,
   n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic',random_state=0,
   reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
   silent=True, subsample=1)
```

Any reason for the error and why both differ despite me saving and loading the same model?

Comment: Can you provide your code snippets where you fit and pickle the model, and then where you load and predict with it? Just seeing the models doesn't really help diagnose anything

Answer (score 3):

## Re-run your model with fit, save, and then load pipeline file like normal.

#### Save Model

```
joblib.dump(pipeline, "xgb1.joblib.dat")
```

#### load model from file

```
loaded_model = joblib.load("xgb1.joblib.dat")
```

After loading the model this way the error will go away. It did for me.